# Show same points of interest in MKMapView as in the Maps application?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, ios

If you look at a location in a MKMapView and in the Maps application, the maps app has a lot more points of interest. Is there a way to get the same items to show up in an MKMapView?

Here is an example: http://drp.ly/1CJWbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least no built in functionality in MapKit.
You'll have to use Google's webservices to fetch those POIs (like Places API). You should have a look at the [Google Places API Web Services](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

Answer (score 2):

Try `[self.mapView setShowsPointsOfInterest:YES];`  (iOS 7 only)